# What is this disease on my lime plant?

Tags: diagnosis, pests, citrus

What is this disease on my lime plant? And how to fix it?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

These are an advanced case of [spider mites](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spider_mite).  The normal colour of the leaves will never return.  For a quick and effective solution:

- make sure the plant is located where there is lots of light. A south east window is ideal.
- remove every leaf cleanly from the base of the stem where it meets the trunk
- get a cloth or paper towel soaked in a little bit of dish soap and water and run it over all parts of the plant that are left
- repeat the application of soap and water every five to seven days at least twice or three times
- wait for new growth, inspect the underside of the leaves for spider mites that look a little bit like grains of salt